# using os.cpu_count() on a pixelbook

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have recently obtained a pixelbook (i7-7Y75) and although I know this processor has 2 cores I wanted to check that nothing odd had happened in the setup of anoconda in crostini (the linux sandbox on a pixelbook) which would only allow me access to one core. I ran the following :

```
# importing os module  
import os 


# Get the number of CPUs 
# in the system using 
# os.cpu_count() method 
cpuCount = os.cpu_count() 

# Print the number of 
# CPUs in the system 
print("Number of CPUs in the system:", cpuCount)
```

To my surprise it came back as 4. I can only think that this is the thread count rather than the core count, but wondered if anyone knew any more about this?

Comment: Yes, it's the thread count. You answered the question yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was. I was just wondering why cpu_count gives the thread count instead of the core count?